# Unexpected results from Union query on Mysql

Tags: mysql, union

I have the following query -

```
(SELECT entry_by_id, description, 
issue_date AS issue_date,
bill_type_id AS account_type, 
amount 
FROM ac_bills 
WHERE issue_date BETWEEN '2015-08-01' and '2015-08-31')  
UNION  
(select officer_id AS entry_by_id, description,
tr_date AS issue_date,
account_type_id AS account_type, 
amount 
FROM ac_transactions 
WHERE ac_transactions.tr_date BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-31' 
AND ac_transactions.account_type_id 
IN (SELECT id FROM account_types WHERE type_of_nature=2))  
ORDER BY issue_date DESC, account_type ASC
```

As you can see -

**1.**  The account_types table (in the sub query) has the column type_of_nature that tells me what type transaction an item is (1=income and 2=expense)

**2.** I am trying to pull all expenses from two tables - ac_bills and ac_transactions.  ac_bills only holds expenses while the ac_transactions can hold any type of transactions (income/expense) and we know what type the transaction is by the account_types table reference.

**The issue** - the query is pulling all types of transactions from the ac_transactions table when, in theory, it should pull only expenses.  Funny thing is - when I run the select query on the ac_transactions alone without the union part, then it successfully pulls only expenses.
I am pulling my hair out!  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what does this give you `select id from account_types where type_of_nature=2`   .... meaning are you happy with that

Comment: Are you sure you are not mistaking results from the first query as inappropriate results from the second? You could try adding `'A' AS source` and `'B' AS source` to the queries for testing to discern where the results came from.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your comments.  @Drew - This query return all the ids from the account_types table where the nature is expense (2).  These ids are references in my ac_transactions table - so I am trying to pull records from ac_transactions table whose account types are of expense.

Comment: still broken then ? if so can you put the schema on sqlfiddle.com with sample data and expected results from it and I can help

Comment: @Uueerdo - I am testing with a small data set - so, yes I do know which records are coming from which table.  I am really sorry about the formatting - as a new member I am still trying to learn the formatting basics :)  Drew - I sure will - give me a few :)

Comment: drewpierce747@gmail.com .... I will post it on sqlfiddle if you want so others can look at it

Comment: My apologies to everyone (especially to Drew :( ) - there  is nothing wrong with this query.  It was an issue with my misunderstanding about the design.  I was told that ac_bills table only held expenses, but it appears otherwise - it also holds incomes.  My first post and I make a fool out of me!

Answer (score 0):

Can you run this... not sure that it's right, but it seems cleaner at least

```
(
 SELECT entry_by_id
      , description
      , issue_date 
      , bill_type_id account_type
      , amount 
   FROM ac_bills 
  where issue_date between '2015-08-01' and '2015-08-31'
)
  union  
(
 select officer_id entry_by_id
      , description
      ,tr_date 
      , account_type_id 
      , amount 
   from ac_transactions 
   join account_types 
     ON account_types.id = ac_transactions.account_type_id 
  where ac_transactions.tr_date between '2015-08-01' and '2015-08-31' 
    and account_types.type_of_nature = 2
)
  ORDER 
     BY issue_date DESC
      , account_type ASC;
```